# How to make regex select multiple but not in between?

Tags: regex

I have a regexp like so:

```
(?ms)###BEGIN###.+###END###
```

It appears to do what I want in that it selects the block of text, but what I really want is for it to select each instance of the block of text, but not anything in between.

Currently this regex also selects "some text in between".

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to ensure only the BEGIN/END blocks of text are selected?  thanks!

Here is the text being processed - note the leading spaces:

```
    some text at the start

    ###BEGIN###
        off to work we go
    ###END###

some text in between


###BEGIN###
    lets go back home
###END###

    some text at the end
```

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes What's the purpose of `\0` in the brackets? Why not `.+?`?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes That's what the `s` modifier in `(?ms)` does, it makes `.` match newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with reluctant quantifire `.+?`:

```
(?ms)###BEGIN###.+?###END###
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/fR8lM9/1)

the `.+` is greedy, so it will match as much as it can, and it is not what you want. With `.+?` regex will match only enough to succeed.